# How to submit the main form on the click of button in JQuery Dialog Box

Tags: jquery

I am using JQuery to submit the form.

I have got the below HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <form id="aspnetForm" action="index_2011.aspx" method="post">
            <div action="#" class="homeWidget">
                <fieldset>       
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="first" for="olciLastName">
                            Last name</label>
                        <input class="input" id="olciLastName" value="" type="text">
                        <div class="clearBoth">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="first" for="olciItinerary">
                            Itinerary number</label>
                        <input class="input itineraryNumber" id="olciItinerary" value="" type="text">
                        <a href="#" class="ico-help">help</a>
                        <div class="clearBoth">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row submit">
                        <span class="form-btn">
                            <input class="submitButton" value="Retrieve Booking" type="button"></span>
                        <div class="clearBoth">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>      
            <!-- SKYWARDS LOGIN -->
            <div style="display: none;" id="skywardsLogin">
                <div class="formContainer" id="loginDetails">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td colspan="2" class="formLabel">
                                <span style="color: Red;" class="validateTips"></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="100" class="formLabel">
                                <label>Skywards Number</label>
                            </td>           
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="formLabel">
                                <label>Password</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="password" class="formField" id="password" maxlength="25" name="password">
                            </td>               
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="formLabel">
                                <label>Remember Me</label>
                            </td>               
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
                    <div class="continueBarRightButton">
                        <input type="image" title="Log In" alt="Log In" id="loginButton" name="loginButton" src="/english/images/button_log_in_tcm233-224930.gif">
                        <div style="display: none;" id="ajaxloading">
                            <img align="absmiddle" alt="Processing..." src="/english/images/spinner.gif">
                             Processing...
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>  
        </form>     
    </div>  
</body>
```

If you see the above HTML, I have got  with ID **skywardsLogin**, Which will work as JQuery Modal Dialog, as if what I know and see that when JQuery **.Dialog** function is called it **tooks all the related HTML** out from the **FORM** tag, my problem is that I want to submit the form of the click of login button **("loginButton")**, I know how to submit the FORM, however question is that I am not getting complete FORM element values when I am doing the submit, below is the Jquery example code which I am using to submit the form.

```
$("#aspnetForm").attr("action", "http://localhost:8080/english/index_2011.aspx");
$("#aspnetForm").submit();
```

I have already checked using serialize, but not getting any form values

```
 var str = $('#aspnetForm').serialize();   
        // -- Start AJAX Call --
 alert(str);
```

Above **ALERT** is not showing any entered values in the form.
Please suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling jquery .dialog() on an element removes everything inside outside the form.  You need to put it back after initializing the dialog.  You can do it in the same chain:

```
$("skywardslogin").dialog({....}).appendTo("form:first");
```

Comment: I have got 35 form fields, so you mean I have to initialize all of them again, something like var skywardsNumberInput = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "skywardsNumber").val($('#skywardsNumber').val());  
var passwordInput = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "password").val($('#password').val());  

and then appending to form again.

$("#aspnetForm").append($(skywardsNumberInput));   
$("#aspnetForm").append($(passwordInput));  I know this, is there any other approach to get all the values of forms element

Comment: No just any elements that you call dialog() on.

Comment: Sorry Adam, I am not able to understand your point, can you please suggest with example code.